# Swift Popover wrong shadow if width <30

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoa-touch, popover

this is the main controller and it's a simple segue for popover from the storyboard. the problem is if i set the width to below 50 weird shadows appears. https://www.dropbox.com/s/bboh6cxnrge6q9g/Screen%20Shot%202015-09-04%20at%202.20.03%20PM.png?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/lrw3ec44m0997q4/Screen%20Shot%202015-09-04%20at%202.20.56%20PM.png?dl=0

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate
{
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
{
if let popupView = segue.destinationViewController as? UIViewController
{
  if let popup = popupView.popoverPresentationController
  {
    popup.delegate = self
           popupView.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 30, height: 250)
          }
}
    }

func adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController(controller:      UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle
{
return UIModalPresentationStyle.None
}

}
```